# How can I know the how many items will be drawn on the screen, so I can put a custom item as the last item. Without scrolling. Using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I want to show items in a grid but not scrollable. How can I know how many items I will draw on the screen based on its height and width. here i am showing only 9 items on the screen and putting the last custom item, but if I have a bigger screen, I don't know how many items will be drawn. How to solve it.

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(120.dp)
    ) {
        if (viewModel.state.value.participantsShown.size > 8) {
            items(viewModel.state.value.participantsShown.subList(0, 8)) {
                Audience(participant = it)
            }
            item {
                OpenAllParticipants(viewModel = viewModel)
            }
        } else {
            items(viewModel.state.value.participantsShown) {
                Audience(participant = it)
            }
            item {
                OpenAllParticipants(viewModel = viewModel)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I measured the available width and height and based on it I decided how many items I will draw.

```
BoxWithConstraints(contentAlignment = Center) {
            val audienceHeight = 120.dp
            val audienceWidth = 120.dp
            val padd = 8.dp
            val paddH = 32.dp
            val col = maxWidth.div(audienceWidth + padd).toInt()
            val row = maxHeight.div(audienceHeight + paddH).toInt()
            println("Col $col")
            println("Row $row")
            val itemsToDraw = (col * row)
            viewModel.state.value.itemsToDraw = itemsToDraw

            LazyVerticalGrid(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                columns = GridCells.Adaptive(120.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
            ) {
                val participantsSize = viewModel.state.value.participantsShown.size
                items(
                    viewModel.state.value.participantsShown.subList(
                        fromIndex = 0,
                        toIndex = minOf(itemsToDraw - 1, participantsSize)
                    )
                ) {
                    Audience(participant = it)
                }
                item {
                    OpenAllParticipants(viewModel = viewModel)
                }
            }
        }
```